# How to run .Server file extension?

Tags: bash

I want to run files from the `.Server` file extension on my Raspberry Pi using bash. How do I run it?
Running `file yourFile.Server` gives me:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Documents/AmongUs-Server $ file Impostor.Server 
Impostor.Server: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=9f83a5d0ada1f3ca20114a778851f8a291b700f4, stripped
```

Comment: That's an x86-64 binary, it's not compiled for the hardware architecture used by Raspberry Pi.  You can't run it natively.

Comment: @AndyDalton There are other options to run arm64, and x64, which one should I choose?

Comment: If you have am arm64 version of that application, you can try that.

Comment: @AndyDalton Thanks, I'll try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.server` is just part of the file-name. There is no such thing as a file-extensions (there was on MS-Windows pre Windows-95, and in CPM ).

The problem is the file-type: it is an executable `ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), …`. The important part of this is `x86-64`, it is the CPU architecture. The Pi has an `ARM` CPU: it is not an `x86`.

Options:

- Get a version of the program that is compiled for your OS and hardware.
- Obtain source code and ask/pay someone to compiled for your OS and hardware.
- Obtain source code and Compile the program for your OS and hardware.